# Updating URL hash without page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

```
<script>
function CurHash(){
    var id = parseInt(window.location.hash.replace("#", ""));
    alert(id);
}
</script>

<!-- START URL: test.htm#1 -->
<a href='#1' onClick='CurHash()'>#1</a>
<a href='#2' onClick='CurHash()'>#2</a>
<a href='#3' onClick='CurHash()'>#3</a>
```

If we are now on test.htm#1 and click link #2, alert shows 1 number, not 2, and after this hash in URL is changed to 2. When you next click 3, it will show prevouse 2, and so on.

There is the problem for me, because I use hash for scrolling my page content on fixed height (can't use anchors due to architecture issues), and with such behavour after clicking link scroll will happened only on second click, what is completely wrong.

QUESTION: **How can I update hash and take updated (not previouse) value for further use, without reloading page in browser (all content for scrolling already on page, reload it from server isn't good solution).**

Comment: Just wanted to let you know WHY: because the "onclick" event is firing BEFORE the hash is updated.

Answer (score 4):

Not exactly cross browser, but you can get cross browser hashchange workarounds if you want,

```
<script>
$(window).on('hashchange load',function(){
    var id = parseInt(window.location.hash.replace("#", ""));
    alert(id);
});
</script>

<!-- START URL: test.htm#1 -->
<a href='#1'>#1</a>
<a href='#2'>#2</a>
<a href='#3'>#3</a>
```

using bind:
http://jsfiddle.net/KdqWK/1/

using on:
http://jsfiddle.net/KdqWK/2/

Comment: Which browsers this will work? I tried without success in FF, Chrome and Opera...

Comment: @DaneSoul please check the fiddle I just added

Comment: @DaneSoul on requires atleat 1.7.1 I guess, else use bind

Answer (score 1):

I would use the **onpopstate** and **onhashchange** event listeners:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

    if (typeof window.onpopstate != 'undefined') {
        window.onpopstate = curHash;
    } else if (typeof window.onhashchange != 'undefined') {
        window.onhashchange = curHash;
    }

    function curHash() {
        var h = window.location.hash;
        if (h == '') return; // no hash. this is probably the first load
        h = h.substr(1); // hash always starts with #
        alert('hash: ' + h);
    }

</script>
</head>

<body>
<ul style="margin:0; padding:0;">
    <li><a href="#1">Click here for 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#2">Click here for 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#3">Click here for 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#4">Click here for 4</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How should I call your code from OnClick on links? I think I am doing something wrong and can't make your code work...

Comment: I have updated my answer. I needed the `typeof` operator, sorry for misleading.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling curHash in onclick, call it in href after setting hash.. please find the following code..

```
<a href='javascript:location.hash="#1";CurHash();'>#1</a>
<a href='javascript:location.hash="#2";CurHash();'>#2</a>
<a href='javascript:location.hash="#3";CurHash();'>#3</a>
```

Comment: Oh, this is interesting solution! Haven't seen such syntax befor, but this works!

Comment: This is not a great solution as the code is sloppy. You should use standard link href for updating the hash and use a library for listening to hashchange events (http://bit.ly/7W6mrl).

Answer (score -1):

You can set the hash value of a URL

```
window.location.hash = '#newhash';
```

You could also just use a JS variable to store what link was clicked and pass that into your code... unless I'm misunderstanding the question.

Comment: this reloads the page, exactly what is NOT wanted